# Can't use boolean variable in inner class

Tags: android, variables, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes within a dialog window. I want to save the checkboxes, after the customer confirmed with a button, that he want to save those settings.
I tried to realize the code above, I cant find a way where I have to declerate the boolean's check1 and check2. Hope anyone can help me, if you need more information, please ask.

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // ....

       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0);
       checkbox1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked" ,false));
       checkbox2.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx2_ischecked" ,false));

     // ...

     checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      check1=isChecked;

     }
    });

    checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     check2=isChecked;

    }

    }); 

      buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0).edit();
                     editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", check1);
                     editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", check2);
                     editor.commit();
                    }
                });

});
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: where is your inner class?! can't see it

Comment: Declare your booleans at the top of your activity, and change `check1=isChecked` to `check1=true`  or `false`

Answer (score 0):

> Choice 1

Add these 2 lines before button click -

```
final boolean checked_1 = check1;
final boolean checked_2 = check2;
```

Then, use these booleans instead inside click event.

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                         Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0).edit();
                         editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", checked_1);
                         editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", checked_2);
                         editor.commit();
                        }
                    });

    });
```

> Choice 2

Declare check1 and check2 in class level, and make it like -

```
boolean check1 = false;
boolean check2 = false; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // ....

       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0);
       checkbox1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked" ,false));
       checkbox2.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx2_ischecked" ,false));

     // ...

     checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      check1=isChecked;

     }
    });

    checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     check2=isChecked;

    }

    }); 

      buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0).edit();
                     editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", check1);
                     editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", check2);
                     editor.commit();
                    }
                });

});
```

Comment: Choose 1: Modifier public not allowed here, Choose 2: 'setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)' in 'android.view.View' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)'

Comment: @Iljaminati I guess...you misunderstood the choice 2...check it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the checked state of button.
Why don't you use isChecked() of Checkbox?
Make checkbox1, checkbox2 are final.
Then

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0).edit();
                 editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", checkbox1.isChecked());
                 editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", checkbox2.isChecked());
                 editor.commit();
                }
            });
```